# EF Lambda include navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have the following object, called Filter with the following properties:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Type> Types{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Flow> Flows { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
```

When I select a list of Filters from the database, I have no idea how to include the collections (Types, Steps, Flows, Rooms). My code is as follows:

```
var filters = (
            from filter in dbContext.DbSet<Filter>()
            let rooms = (
                from r in dbContext.DbSet<Room>()
                select r
                )
            let eventTypes = (
                from t in dbContext.DbSet<Type>()
                select t
                )
            let processFlows = (
                from f in dbContext.DbSet<Flow>()
                select f
                )
            let processFlowSteps = (
                from s in dbContext.DbSet<Step>()
                select s
                )
            select filter
            ).ToList();
```

My collection of Filter is returned, but the collections inside are empty. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this?

Ps: I do not want to use Include because of performance issues, I don't like how Entity Framework generates the query and I would like to do it this way.

Comment: Why not use `dbContext.Filters` instead of `dbContext.DbSet<Filter>()`?

Comment: @juharr thats effectivelly the same thing, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: *" I don't like how Entity Framework generates the query and I would like to do it this way*" What do you mean by "this way"? If you mean the shown code, apparently it doesn't work, hence definitely cannot be "the way". And even if you include the `let `variables in the `select` (e.g. `select new { filter, rooms, etc.... }`), the resulting query will be much worse than the one with `Include` because `let` queries will be executed for each record of `Filter` table. And the result set will be full cartesian product. Sounds like XY problem to me.

Comment: just load each navigation one by one, I am not sure why you need the let. You could just materialize the filters, then do the same for each collection, but this time you don't need to store the result. The filters should be populated.

Comment: With lazy loading you do not need to be include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works, you are just doing it slighly wrong.

To include a navigation property, all you have to do is a subselect (using linq), example:

```
var filters = (from filter in dbContext.DbSet<Filter>()
                select new Filter
                {
                    filter.Id,
                    filter.Name,
                    Rooms = (from r in dbContext.DbSet<Room>()
                            where r.FilterId == filter.Id
                            select r).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Keep in mind that EF won't execute the query until you call a return method (ToList, Any, FirstOrDefault, etc). With this, instead of doing those ugly queries you want to avoid by not using Include(), it will simply fire two queries and properly assign the values in the object you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_Include__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) extension method:

```
var filters=dbContext.DbSet<Filter>()
                     .Include(f=>f.Types)
                     .Include(f=>f.Steps)
                     .Include(f=>f.Flows)
                     .Include(f=>f.Rooms)
                     .ToList()
```

### Update

@MrSilent, `Include` extension method was made exactly for the purpose of loading related entities, I think the other option you have is executing a [raw sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), but the way you are doing is not the way to go you have four roundtrips to your database and you need to use join instead in order to get the related entities, `Include` generates those joins for you and it's just one roundtrip.

This is, eg, another way I guess you could do it, but again, it is against the purpose of using EF, the idea of your model is also to represent the relationship between your tables, not just to represent them individually

```
var query= from f in context.DbSet<Filter>()
           from s in f.Steps
           from r in f.Rooms
           from t in f.Types
           from fl in f.Flows
           select new {f, s, r, t, fl};
```

Comment: I down voted by mistake, I am truly sorry. Been an exhausting week. I do not want to use Include because of performance issues, I don't like how Entity Framework generates the query and I would like to do it this way.

Comment: This answer does exactly what the question asks, "include navigation properties".

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading , how :

You first need to get the properties that are Include inclined to be virtual and then an empty constructor that is protected access type to do your job well.

```
public virtual ICollection<Type> Types{ get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Flow> Flows { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
```

And

```
 //FOR EF !
 protected Filter() { }
```

I think this solution will solve your problem.